# Finding Local Maxima

Tags: haskell

The following function finds all local maxima.

A local maxima is an element of a list such that it's greater than either of its neighbor elements. An element with 1 neighbor is not a local maximum.

```
localMaxima :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
localMaxima (x:y:z:zs) = if (y > x && y > z) then y : localMaxima (y:z:zs) 
                         else localMaxima (y:z:zs)
localMaxima _          = []
```

Please critique it.

Examples:

```
ghci> localMaxima [1,3,2,55,2] 
[3,55]
ghci> localMaxima [1,3,2,55,1000000000]
[3]
```

Comment: Non-recursive oneliner: `locmax xs = map (\(x, y, z) -> x) . filter (\(x, y, z) -> x > y && x > z) $ zip3 (drop 1 xs) xs (drop 2 xs)`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have redundant parentheses here: `(y > x && y > z)`. You can also make your type more generic: `localMaxima :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`.

I think it looks a bit cleaner using an as-pattern and guard clauses. This way you don't need `zs` and can just write `_`.

```
localMaxima (x:rest@(y:z:_))
  | y > x && y > z = y : localMaxima rest
  | otherwise      = localMaxima rest
localMaxima _ = []
```

In fact, if you know that `y > z` then you don't need to check if `z` is a local maximum.